# How best to share maps created in MapInfo Online

Tags: mapinfo, online

Does anyone know of a good free or low cost option for sharing Maps produced in mapinfo online?

I would want up to 5 users to access the maps with a password and be able to turn layers / points on and off and zoom in and out.

Basically I am looking to upload the Mapinfo files or Shapefiles and create thematic maps (ideally multivariate) online.

I have looked at Mapinfo Stratus but costs are prohibitive for a small company (<5 people)!

Many thanks for any help

Kev

Comment: mapworkspace http://www.mapworkspace.com/ there is a limited free version (5mb) - there are other options if you have your own webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Another low cost option would be to share your maps using a layered GeoPDF.

With the MapInfo PDF Printer Driver you can create a PDf document that holds coordinates.

You can also create the PDF document as a layered document where the end user can turn layers on and off once he has the document open.

And finally you can choose to add some attribute information to the PDF document as well - for a single, few or all your layers.

Comment: Hi Peter

Many thanks for your message.

This is a good option where you do not need to zoom in to certain areas but has its limitations if your customer wants to see the bigger picture of the UK  but also drill into the detail in London.

Comment: Yeah, it's a static map. You could however add extra detail maps to the document and they user could turn on and off the entire map and not just a single layer. But still a basic static map.